# ON CONFLICT (primary_key_column)DO UPDATE SET - postgreSQL not working by using WSO2 DSS in WSO2 EI 6.4.0

Tags: postgresql, wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-data-services-server

I am performing an upsert operation using PostgreSQL 11.6 Table using `WSO2 DSS` in WSO2 EI 6.4.0

**Table Data:**

```
dev_source  dev_id  dev_name
cloud       Cloud   Device
amazon      ec2     Ec2
solaris     4737    Web
```

where `dev_id` is `primary key`

DSS- Code:

```xml
<data name="WSO2_test_DSS" transports="http https local">
   <config enableOData="false" id="ZCloudDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
      <property name="url">jdbc:postgresql://postgreurl:5432/test_schema</property>
      <property name="username">username</property>
      <property name="password">password</property>
   </config>
   
   <query id="dev_insert_Q" returnUpdatedRowCount="true" useConfig="ZCloudDataSource">
      <sql>insert into  zcloudtest.dev_test (dev_source,dev_id,dev_name) values(?,?,?) ON CONFLICT (dev_id) DO UPDATE SET (dev_source,dev_name)=(excluded.dev_source,excluded.dev_name)</sql>
      <result element="UpdatedRowCount" rowName="" useColumnNumbers="true">
         <element column="1" name="Value" xsdType="integer"/>
      </result>
      <param name="dev_source" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="dev_id" sqlType="STRING"/>
      <param name="dev_name" sqlType="STRING"/>
   </query>
   
   <operation name="dev_insert_op">
      <call-query href="dev_insert_Q">
         <with-param name="dev_source" query-param="tenant"/>
         <with-param name="dev_id" query-param="source"/>
         <with-param name="dev_name" query-param="device_id"/>
      </call-query>
   </operation>
</data>
```

I need to `upsert` the data rather than plain insert. So used `ON CONFLICT (dev_id) DO UPDATE SET` feature mentioned [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-upsert/)  in `query` to achieve the same.

Even though added above `ON CONFLICT` to query, It is below mentioned throwing ERROR.

ERROR Log:

```
[2023-03-20 11:33:36,610] [-1234] [] [PassThroughMessageProcessor-42] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver} -  Error in in-out message receiver
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dev_test_pkey"
  Detail: Key (dev_id)=(Cloud) already exists.
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: WSO2_test_DSS
Location: /home/wso2carbon/wso2ei-6.4.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/test-ETL_CAR_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.car/WSO2_test_DSS_1.0.0/WSO2_test_DSS-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: device_inventory_insert_op
Current Params: {dev_name=Device, dev_id=Cloud, dev_source=Cloud}
Nested Exception:-
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dev_test_pkey"
  Detail: Key (dev_id)=(Cloud) already exists.


    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.DataServiceRequest.dispatch(DataServiceRequest.java:359)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DataServiceProcessor.dispatch(DataServiceProcessor.java:41)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(DBInOutMessageReceiver.java:57)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutSyncMessageReceiver.java:42)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:337)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:383)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in 'SQLQuery.processPreNormalQuery': ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dev_test_pkey"
  Detail: Key (dev_id)=(Cloud) already exists.
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: WSO2_test_DSS
Location: /home/wso2carbon/wso2ei-6.4.0/wso2/tmp/carbonapps/-1234/test-ETL_CAR_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.car/WSO2_test_DSS_1.0.0/WSO2_test_DSS-1.0.0.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice
Current Request Name: device_inventory_insert_op
Current Params: {dev_name=Device, dev_id=Cloud, dev_source=Cloud}
Nested Exception:-
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "dev_test_pkey"
  Detail: Key (dev_id)=(Cloud) already exists.

    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.engine.DSOMDataSource.execute(DSOMDataSource.java:102)
    at org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.dispatch.SingleDataServiceRequest.processRequest(SingleDataServiceRequest.java:73)
    ... 13 more
```

The same Sort of ERROR I've got when used plain `insert` query, so  modified query with `ON CONFLICT` to do upsert operation. Still it throws ERROR? This means `ON CONFLICT` not working in DSS?

PS: Insert query with ON CONFLICT is working fine in workbench and updated row in table

Comment: Which driver version are you using? Did you try using the latest driver?

Comment: Hi @ycr
I am using Postgresql driver version 42.2.2. May i know which version u r suggesting?

Comment: I don't think the driver version is related to your issue. I was able to do an upsert with 42.2.2. The sql query looks fine as well.

Comment: Hi @sanoJ
Thanks for your input. If there is no issue with query and driver, why i'm getting ERROR like "duplicate key value violates unique constraint". Do you have any idea to fix the same?

Comment: @Justin Can you try to add a debug logger `log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.dataservices=DEBUG` to log4j.properties and check whether the SQL query is generated properly?